# android-How to set the text size of list item in alert dialog

Tags: android

In My application one button is there when you click on that one alert dialog will be appear. that alert dialog consists of single choice list items. Here i want to set the text size of single choice list item. 
is it possible? if yes how to do it.

The following is my code

**sclist.java**

```
package com.examples.scl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class sclist extends Activity {

 private static final int DIALOG_SINGLE_CHOICE = 1;


  @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_SINGLE_CHOICE:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(sclist.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle("Single choice list")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.select_dialog_items2, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked on a radio button do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked Yes so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked No so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
               .create();
        }
        return null;
        }

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    /* Display a radio button group */
    Button radioButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
    radioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_SINGLE_CHOICE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Also, do a search before you ask a question. This question has been answered before.

Comment: Really? Because I am searching for this exact thing, and I can't find an answer. There are answers about how to change the format of the _message_ in the alert dialog, but not the _singleChoiceItems_. If you see it answered somewhere else, a link would be helpful.

Answer (score 14):

I just encountered this problem myself on a matching game I'm working on.  My solution isn't simple but I wanted to use a custom font, and I didn't see an easy way to do it with the 2.2 Android interface (which is what I'm targeting).  The trick is to attach an OnShowListener to the alert dialog before you show it.  In that listener, get ListAdapter out of the ListView and wrap it with a proxy object that forwards all the calls except the getView.  In that function, cast the View to a TextView, set the typeface and size, and return the view.  Here's my code:

```
                    // Add your list with builder up here
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface alert) {
                ListView listView = ((AlertDialog)alert).getListView();
                final ListAdapter originalAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

                listView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter()
                {

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        return originalAdapter.getCount();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getItem(int id) {
                        return originalAdapter.getItem(id);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getItemId(int id) {
                        return originalAdapter.getItemId(id);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getItemViewType(int id) {
                        return originalAdapter.getItemViewType(id);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = originalAdapter.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView textView = (TextView)view;
                        textView.setTypeface(MyFontUtil.getTypeface(MyActivity,MY_DEFAULT_FONT));
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textView.setTextSize(25); // FIXIT - absolute size 
                        return view;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getViewTypeCount() {
                        return originalAdapter.getViewTypeCount();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean hasStableIds() {
                        return originalAdapter.hasStableIds();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isEmpty() {
                        return originalAdapter.isEmpty();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                        originalAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                        originalAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                        return originalAdapter.areAllItemsEnabled();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                        return originalAdapter.isEnabled(position);
                    }

                });

            }

        });


        alert.show();
```

If you want to see it in action look on the Android Market in a few weeks.  Search for metaphyze (my publisher id).  I haven't decided what to call it yet.  (It's not "FlashMatch Chinese I Free".  That was my first game.  This is a kid's matching game.  Play the game and tap the picture at the end.  You'll see the AlterDialog with the style list.).

Comment: I know it's old, but it helped me for something similar (in a ListPreference), so +1

Comment: +1 The OP (Question) and the above answer helped me get an idea of how  I can set the color and other properties. But as in my [Question asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040245/how-to-extract-view-or-item-id-from-a-dynamic-multi-choice-items-list-in-a-alert) How can I get ItemID or set the color and other properties individually for an item on click? Suppose if I click a single item in the list and want the clicked item to have a green background/text color?

Comment: Awesome answer. Was looking to use a different custom font for each line in the `ListView`, this was by far the best way I found to accomplish this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I believe you'd have to use the AlertDialog.Builder constructor that also takes a theme [AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int theme)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context,%20int%29), see if you can see anything useful in that description, I've never tried it myself.

Comment: sadly only available since API 11